# 400 Bad request error Ajax call to Spring controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

When I am posting the Ajax request getting the error request:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "jsp/stdregistration.do",
        data : "stdFirstName=" + stdFirstName + "&stdMiddleName=" + stdMiddleName + "&stdLastName=" + stdLastName +"&yoa=" + yoa + "&stdcode=" + stdcode + "&aadharno=" + aadharno +"&palceofbirth=" + palceofbirth + "&dob=" + dob + "&doa=" + doa +"&mothertoung=" + mothertoung + "&otherlang1=" + otherlang1 + "&otherlang2=" + otherlang2,
```

But If I am posting the same request with less parameter I am not getting error
Example:

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "jsp/stdregistration.do",
        data : "stdFirstName=" + stdFirstName + "&stdMiddleName=" + stdMiddleName + "&stdLastName=" + stdLastName + "&mothertoung=" + mothertoung + "&otherlang1=" + otherlang1 + "&otherlang2=" + otherlang2,
```

Please help me out to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: Both looks  **OK**. Can you please show codes , where you assign values in variables like *yoa, dob, doa* etc.

Comment: Hi, SHAZ thanks for reply, actually Iam new to stackoverflow,I already tested the assigned value and they are working perfectly.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: My Error is Like this:
POST localhost:1011/SMS/jsp/stdregistration.do 400 (Bad Request)